# How to check if something is within a range of multiple items in a list?

Tags: python, list, pygame

```
import pygame
display_width = 600
display_height = 600
snake_List = [[120.0, 180.0], [120.0, 240.0], [120.0, 300.0], [120.0, 360.0], [180.0, 360.0], [240.0, 360.0], [300.0, 360.0], [300.0, 420.0], [240.0, 420.0], [180.0, 420.0], [120.0, 420.0]]
food_placed = False
snake_block_size = 60

def Food(snake_List, food_placed, foodX, foodY):
    while food_placed == False:
        foodX = round(random.randrange(0,display_width))
        foodY = round(random.randrange(0,display_height))
        food_pos = [foodX,foodY]
        if food_pos in snake_List:
            food_placed = False
        else:
            food_placed = True
```

I am making a snake game and have a problem with the food-spawn because it spawns on the snake. The solution I came up with doesn't work because it only will not spawn in the snake if it spawns exactly at the position of the snake being drawn.
So I need it to check if it is within the 60 block range.

```
def Food(snake_List, food_placed, foodX, foodY):
    foodX = round(random.randrange(0,display_width))
    foodY = round(random.randrange(0,display_height))
    food_pos = [foodX,foodY]
    if food_pos[1] + 60  < snake_List[0::2] and food_pos[2] + 60 < snake_List[1::2]:
        food_placed = False
    elif food_pos[1] - 60  > snake_List[1::2] and food_pos[1] - 60 > snake_List[0::2]:
        food_placed = False
    else:
        food_placed = True
```

This was my attempted solution but it says "'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'"

Comment: `snake_List[1::2]` is a (sub)list you cannot compare a list with an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the snake to a list of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects:

```py
snake_block_size = 60
snake_List = [[120.0, 180.0], [120.0, 240.0], [120.0, 300.0], [120.0, 360.0], [180.0, 360.0], [240.0, 360.0], [300.0, 360.0], [300.0, 420.0], [240.0, 420.0], [180.0, 420.0], [120.0, 420.0]]
```

```py
snake_rect_list = [pygame.Rect(x, y, snake_block_size, snake_block_size) for x, y in snake_List]
```

Use [`collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) to check whether the foot intersects the snake. See [`collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

> Test whether the rectangle collides with any in a sequence of rectangles. The index of the first collision found is returned. If no collisions are found an index of -1 is returned.

Fucntion `Food`:

```py
def Food(snake_List):
    
    foodX = round(random.randrange(0, display_width))
    foodY = round(random.randrange(0, display_height))
    fodd_size = 60

    food_rect = pygame.Rect(foodX, foodY, fodd_size, fodd_size)
    snake_rect_list = [pygame.Rect(x, y, snake_block_size, snake_block_size)
        for x, y in snake_List]

    if food_rect.collidelist(snake_rect_list) >= 0:
        return None 

    return foodX, foodY
```

---

Note that Python has no concept of in-out parameters. Therefore you have to return the result of the function. Use the function as follows:

```py
food_pos = Food(snake_List)
while food_pos == None:
    food_pos = Food(snake_List)

foodX, foodY = food_pos
```

Comment: Thank you for helping so much but this is probably me being stupid but it didnt work for me so I am currently constructing another question

Comment: @D.CMorgan Of course, it will work for you too. However, I can't guess what you did wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I found it and now i feel really stupid because what I called the food function in the wrong place, so thank you so much